# Image not showing with img src

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug

image :- root_folder\views\img\home_bg.jpg

pug file:- root_folder\views\index.pug

css file:- root_folder\views\assets\css\style.css

[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Piaoa.png)

I am trying to create simple site using NodeJS, I've no knowledge of pug coding but I used html to pug converter to create a pug file.

Here is my html code for 'content' container with img tag and path

```
      <div class="content">
        <img src="/views/img/home_bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
```

and here is my pug code for the same:-

```
      .content
         img(src='../../Project 1/views/img/home_bg.jpg' alt='')
```

here is my output using pug:-

[pug results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGuMz.png)

here is my output using html:-

[result which i get using html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Lum.jpg)

what can be the valid path in pug template? please advise?

Comment: "Project 1" contain a whitespace, it can cause the problem

Comment: @AdamP. No it doesn't work, even after renaming the root folder

Answer (score 0):

have you tried out to remove one `../`, or to put the same src link as in the html, I see that the image isn't loading, so this is just an assumption that maybe the src link is not working.

`/views/img/home_bg.jpg`

```css
 .content
         img(src='../Project 1/views/img/home_bg.jpg' alt='')
```

Maybe this could help.

Comment: Yes, I tried as you suggested, yet no difference image isn't loading. Indeed It is path issues, as it is incorrect I am not able to access the correct image file. On html I can easily access using emmet but here I am having hard time.

Answer (score 0):

```
image :- root_folder\views\img\home_bg.jpg

pug file:- root_folder\views\index.pug

css file:- root_folder\views\assets\css\style.css

file directory

I am trying to create simple site using NodeJS, I've no knowledge of pug coding but I used html to pug converter to create a pug file.

Here is my html code for 'content' container with img tag and path

      <div class="content">
        <img src="/views/img/home_bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
```

pathes you give, always are relative to the file that contains the path.

The path: `<img src="/views/img/home_bg.jpg" alt="">` will lead to the folder: `root_folder/views/views/img/home_bg.jpg` which does not exist. the correct tag should be:

```
<div class="content">
  <img src="img/home_bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

The same applies to this code line:  `.content img(src='../../Project 1/views/img/home_bg.jpg' alt='')` it will move 2 folder below and lead to: `root_folder/Project 1/views/img/home_bg.jpg` which also does not exist according to your file directory.

Comment: .content
    img(src='img/home_bg.jpg' alt='')
- I tried this, but it doesn't work.